# Weird custom annotation behaviour when adding/removing annotations

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am in the middle of developing an application for iOS and have come across an issue with custom annotations on my map view.

**Here is the idea:**

1) I load in the users location to the map, from this location I send a request to my back end server to retrieve all nearby points of interest.

2) I have a custom annotation as follows:

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String?
    var activeImageName : String?
    var trainCrossingId : Int?
    var notificationCount : UILabel = UILabel()
    var labelIsHidden : Bool = true
}
```

when I add the annotations onto the map, I am dynamically setting the `notificationCount` label to use data that I have retrieved from my Firebase Database.

3) A user is able to increase/decrease the size of the radius around their current location.  With this new radius selected, I use `mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)` to remove all annotations and then re-add these annotations with the new data retrieved from the server using the selected radius.

**The Issue:**

When initially loading the view, the annotations are working as expected with the correct labels set etc.

However, once a user updates the radius and I remove/add the previous annotations, the annotations and their corresponding labels are not showing as expected.

For example, this is what the map looks like when first entering into the view:

[image]

And then once I change the size of the radius:
[image]

The expected data is what is shown in the initial image (when first entering the view), but when the radius is updated the z-value of my annotations are not respected, and `notificationCount` is not correct (eg, the third point found in the second diagram should not have a label).  This is weird as I have set up print statements and break points to monitor each annotation in `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {...}` and the values are correct and what I expect, however the view is not displaying these values.

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong here?  Thanks in advance!

**Edit to include the following mapView delegate:**

```
 // Custom annotation view
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "trainPin"

        var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if anView == nil {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        }
        else {
            anView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
        let icon : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
        icon.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)
        icon.layer.zPosition = 1
        anView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = cpa.annotationButton
        anView?.addSubview(cpa.notificationCount)
        anView?.addSubview(icon)
        anView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width:32, height:32)
        anView?.canShowCallout = true
        return anView
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code for `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`?

Comment: Sure, I have just edited to add it in to the original question.  Thanks @chengsam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that as `anView` will be reused, the view will have many subviews as you remove and add annotations. Try to remove the subviews first then add again:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "trainPin"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
    }
    else {
        anView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
    let icon : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
    icon.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)
    icon.layer.zPosition = 1
    anView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = cpa.annotationButton
    for view in anView?.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperView()
    }
    anView?.addSubview(cpa.notificationCount)
    anView?.addSubview(icon)
    anView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width:32, height:32)
    anView?.canShowCallout = true
    return anView
}
```

Comment: This did the trick!  Thank you so much chengsam, I very much appreciate your help - I don't think I would have caught onto the subview issue!

Comment: @Dayna I just saw your previous comment said this does not work. Did you do anything different?

Comment: was my fault, did not build properly and therefore code was not updated haha!  Rebuilt and it is now working - thank you again, you saved me tons of time :)